# \vec{x} but with arrow from right to left?

Tags: macros, vector

I have two variables: `\vec{x}` and another one which is somehow dual to the first. Therefore I would like to symbolize the second with something similar but a leftarrow on top of the x. I already tried `\stackrel{leftarrow}{x}` but it looks to different (too big gap between x and the arrow, and too big arrow).

Is there a way to define a `\cev` command which does what I want?

Comment: I just encountered a simple solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826471/latex-left-arrow-over-letter-in-math-mode

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This may not be the best way, but two `\reflectbox` commands will do the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\cev}[1]{\reflectbox{\ensuremath{\vec{\reflectbox{\ensuremath{#1}}}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\vec{a} \quad \cev{a} \quad \vec{b} \quad \cev{b}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this causes problems with subscripts: [Example](http://i.imgur.com/VnSJLxz.png) On the right hand side the `t` is marked using `\cev{t_{\mathring{r}}}` and `s` is marked using `\cev{s}_{\mathring{r}}`  I'd like to have the arrow centered over the whole symbol (including subscript) as it is in the case of `t` on the left.

Comment: In your example, the arrow over the `t` on the left does not appear to be centred over the whole symbol including the superscript to me. On the other hand, `\cev{t_{\mathring{r}}}` seems to give exactly what you want.

Comment: `\cev{t_{\mathring{r}}}` is shown on the right. And `\cev{t_r}` is shown on the left, where the arrow is a bit more centered than in the case of `\cev{t}_r`. I'm happy with the looks on the left side, but the right side obviously is wrong.

Comment: This could be a problem with the font you are using; the result of `\cev{t_{\mathring{r}}}` on my machine looks nothing like yours! Please post a new question with a complete example code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I can't use `\cev` in figure captions?

Comment: @Matt --- try `\protect\cev{x}`

Comment: @IanThompson, that did the trick. Cheers

Answer (score 23):

A `\cev` command that seems to give good results on most letters and works correctly (apart a very small drift) in subscripts and superscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,accents}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cev}[1]{%
  \mathpalette\do@cev{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\do@cev}[2]{%
  \fix@cev{#1}{+}%
  \reflectbox{$\m@th#1\vec{\reflectbox{$\fix@cev{#1}{-}\m@th#1#2\fix@cev{#1}{+}$}}$}%
  \fix@cev{#1}{-}%
}
\newcommand{\fix@cev}[2]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \mkern#23mu
  \else
    \ifx#1\textstyle
      \mkern#23mu
    \else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle
        \mkern#22mu
      \else
        \mkern#22mu
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
$Xx$

$X\cev{x}_{\cev{x}_{\cev{x}}}$ $\cev{a}\cev{b}\cev{m}\cev{X}$

$X\vec{x}_{\vec{x}_{\vec{x}}}$ $\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{m}\vec{X}$

$\cev{\imath}$

$\vec{\imath}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

A different implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cev}[1]{%
  {\mathpalette\do@cev{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\do@cev}[2]{%
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1 x$}%
    \ialign{##\cr
      \hidewidth\reflectbox{$\m@th#1\vec{}\mkern4mu$}\hidewidth\cr
      \noalign{\kern-\ht\z@}
      $\m@th#1#2$\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$Xx$

$X\cev{x}_{\cev{x}_{\cev{x}}}$ $\cev{a}\cev{b}\cev{m}\cev{X}$

$X\vec{x}_{\vec{x}_{\vec{x}}}$ $\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{m}\vec{X}$

$\cev{\imath}$

$\vec{\imath}$

$\cev{\sigma}\cev{x}$
$\vec{\sigma}\vec{x}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can the arrow be rotated instead of reflected to have the correct slanting? Now, the `\cev` arrow slants to the left, while the `\vec` arrow (as well as the italic letter) slants to the right.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel That's more difficult.

Comment: @user49915 I get [picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQSLm.png), which doesn't show so big a difference with `\cev{x}`

Comment: @user49915 Maybe you want to try the different implementation I added, maybe fixing the amount of `\mkern`.

Comment: @user49915 On the other hand, `\vec{\sigma}` is very bad with `newtxmath`.

Answer (score 11):

The extensible `\overleftarrow` might do the trick. The problem is that the arrow is bigger than the one used for `\vec`, as shown by `\[\overleftarrow{a}\overrightarrow{a}\vec{a}\]` . To have consistent arrows, you should redefine $\vec$ :

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\renewcommand\vec[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}
\newcommand\cev[1]{\overleftarrow{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[\cev{a}\vec{a}\]
\end{document}
```

**Edited to add:**

Another solution is the `\overset` command from `amsmath`, used with `\leftarrow`. However, the arrow is still bigger than the one from the `\vec` 
command.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\overset{\leftarrow}{v}\overset{\rightarrow}{v}\vec{v}\]
\end{document}
```

**Edited to add **
 Using `\shortleftarrow` from the `stmaryrd` package slightly improves the above construction.

Answer (score 6):

The `\vec` is an accent (and its own symbol; hence all `\leftarrow` and similar  constructs look different), and the default Computer Modern font doesn't have a symbol which would be its mirror.

In addition to rotating/mirroring the vec accent symbol, as shown by Ian, you could make use of one provided by, say, STIX/XITS (if you use XeTeX).
Then you could define:

```
\def\cev{\XeTeXmathaccent"0"1"20D6}
% The first number ("0) denotes the math type (0=Ord,1=Op,2=Bin,3=Rel,etc.)
% The second number ("1) denotes the math family (0=Roman,1=Italic,etc.)
% The last number ("20D6) denotes the actual glyph slot
$\cev a \qquad \vec a$
```

Which could look like: [image: cevvec]

Answer (score 6):

I have a little to add to Frederic's solution:

```
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\overset{\shortleftarrow}{a} \quad \vec{a} \quad \overset{{}_{\shortleftarrow}}{a}
```

Basically, the arrow in the subscript makes it smaller and reduces the vertical space between it and the variable. Unfortunately, nesting doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eberhard Mattes provided in the 90s an extra font called emsy containing the missing arrow. The file is downloadable here

https://www.pcorner.com/list/EMTEX

Anyway, it's not easy to use since you have to put the .mf and .tfm files in the correct directory. Once this is done, you may define

```
\newcommand{\cev}[1]{\mathaccent"7A00{\mkern1mu{#1}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Copied from [What is to `\vec` as `\overleftarrow` is to `\overrightarrow`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693044/))

The standard Computer Modern Math font only has a right arrow (in position "7E or 126 in decimal). It has however no left arrow.
[image]

The STIX font provides both a left arrow (in position "91 or 145 in decimal) and a right arrow (in position "92 or 146 in decimal).
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixletters}{LS1}{stix}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathAccent{\cev}{\mathord}{stixletters}{"91}
\DeclareMathAccent{\vec}{\mathord}{stixletters}{"92}
\DeclareMathAccent{\vecev}{\mathord}{stixletters}{"95}


\begin{document}

$\vec{a}, \cev{a}$

$\vec{A}, \cev{A}$

Bonus: $\vecev{a}, \vecev{A}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems interesting. However if I run this on debian 12 with texlive installed I get the error: `The nfss system isn't set up properly.` The answer should mention some non-standard dependency.