# Symbol for qft derivative

Tags: spacing, symbols

I searched a bit on the internet, but I could not find any answer. Studying quantum field theory and Dirac equation I had to write this symbol `$\overset{\leftarrow}{\partial}$`, but the problem is that there is so much vertical space between the arrow and the derivative symbol, so much that I cannot insert the whole of it in the middle of an argument, because it ruins the spacing between lines. I looked in `physics,amsmath` and other packages, but I cannot find any implementation of this symbol, so I'm asking myself if there is any somewhere, or at least how can I solve the vertical spacing problem (should I define a new symbol by myself?). Thanks

Comment: Couldn't `\vec{\partial}` be used?

Comment: I'm exactly looking for something like this, but with the arrow pointing left!

Comment: Oops! I didn't notice \LEFTarrow.

Comment: Maybe I found a temporary solution thanks to you! With the '\vec' suggestion I checked this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15010/vecx-but-with-arrow-from-right-to-left  and found the answer from egreg very useful (following instead the first answer the arrow was misaligned to the symbol). I still wait anyway if someone has a complete answer, but for the moment I can work with this, so thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the vertical space between the (smaller) arrow and the `\partial` symbol.

This only works for text size, so not in subscripts or superscripts: if needed it can be made to work also in those cases.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\qftder}{%
  \mathord{%
    \vbox{\offinterlineskip
      \ialign{\hfil##\cr$\scriptscriptstyle\leftarrow$\cr$\partial$\cr}
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1][1-3] $\qftder$ \lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot egreg. I didn't understand the phrase "This only works for text size, so not in subscripts or superscripts", what do you mean with this?

Comment: And also another question: in your answer that I cited in the link, you define a '\cev' command that seems to be quite universal, while in this case you are defining a specific "object" that is '\qftder', am I right? Sorry for the dumbness I just want to understand the way code works

Comment: @Rob I hope you don't have `\frac{\qftder X}{2}` inside normal text or `X_{\qftder Y}`.

Comment: @Rob You're better in searching than I. ;-) I remembered something like that and possibly `\cev` is what you need.

Comment: Sure I cannot put '\qftder' inside normal text because seems to work in just math mode, is that what are you saying? Both '\qftder' and '\cev' are very good, I will try both in the time and I'll choose. :)

Comment: @Rob I meant something like `text $\frac{\qftder X}{2}$ other text`

Comment: @egreeg Yes I tried it and I get what you mean! Yes, but I don't normally use '\frac' command inside text because I don't like the way it seems: I would use instead '$\qftder X/2$ so no problem for that, thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

You have a recent dedicated package: `letterswitharrows` .

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{letterswitharrows} 

\begin{document}
 \[ \arrowoverset*\partial \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great too thanks!

Comment: Just a curiosity, if you know: why in your opinion is this not implemented in 'physics' package? In quantum field theory these kind of symbols seem to be used a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I'm only a mathematician and I have no idea. This package, it seems, fills a gap.

Comment: Okay just if you knew. Thanks, I will try the package!

Comment: Note the position of the arrow takes into account the italic angle of the symbol.

Comment: So fundamentally the commands in the package don't generate alignment problem, is that what you mean?

Comment: I didn't test it really, but what I mean is that  it may happen  an over arrow or an over line be positioned as though it was over a character in upshape, so we have to compensate with math kerning

Comment: So the arrow or the line are positioned like there is a character that is lined up with the vertical of the page ('upshape' command?) and to adjust it for tilded signs a kerning (this kerning? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) was used. My knowledge is very basic sorry. Anyway if that was what you meant, the example in your figure is very clear; the arrow seems to be perfectly aligned with the '\partial' symbol, so yes, it was a good work :)

Comment: Yes, it is as though the bounding box of the glyph were a parallelogram instead of a rectangle, if you see what I mean. The problem may happen in particular with the `\widebar` command (which has a solution on this site).

Comment: Oh yes. Sometimes this happens with '\hat' or 'bar' or similar commands

Answer (score 1):

There is also another alternative using a rare package named `halloweenmath` with the command `\overscriptleftarrow{...}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{halloweenmath}
\begin{document}
Today is not halloween :-) $\overscriptleftarrow{\partial}$!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I saw it somewhere, I didn't know there was type of command just there! Thanks